# Access SQL Query to search value in 2 tables but use just one?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have 2 tables in MS Access and need to query them looking for a value. If the value is in A, then use that. If value is in B, then use that. If the value is in both tables, then use only the value from table A.

How can I make a query to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: and how are both tables related?  sounds like a join but you must provide structure to get an anwser

Comment: I'd use `SELECT ... FROM A UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM B` and then filter out second value (if present) on client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT  IIF(IsNull(AField),(SELECT AField FROM Table2 WHERE ID=16), AField)
FROM Table1
WHERE ID=16
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an entire table rather than 1 row :-

```
select C1, C2 from TableA where C2 is not null 
union all 
select C1, C2 from TableB where C1 in ( select c1 from TableA where C2 is null )
```